# How to get the possition of an array to which I have a pointer pointing?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have been trying to do this pointer excercise but I dont seem to find my error.
The exercise consists on writing a function to print the information of an array of names, I want the position, the length of each name and the string of the name. You should also know that startPos points to the position in the array names to which each Name starts. [Description of arrays in the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqQK9.png)

```
void printNames(char names[], char *startPos[], int nrNames){
  
  for(int i = 0; i < nrNames; i++){
    printf("startPos[%d]=%02d length=%02d string=%c%s%c\n",i , names[*startPos[i]],
     names[*startPos[i+1]]-names[*startPos[i]],'"', startPos[i],'"');
  }
}
```

The first %02d is suposed to give me the position in my array where the first name is. So for example if i have an array **Asterix\0Obelix\0\0\0\0...** that should return me 00 for Asterix and 08 for Obelix. The thing is, when I try to print the position in the array and the length they both work incorectly. This is what I get when i compile it:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvbxq.png)
As you can see, the output doesn't make sense because the positions shoud change and the length should be the number of characters each name has + the \0 char.
I have tried so many different ways to fix it but none of them work.
Hope somebody can help me with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of text but post text as properly formatted text. This applies to your ["output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvbxq.png). Also [edit] and post a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to SO. `*startPos[i]` This is the first `char` of the string, not the position. You need to check again what `startPos` is.

Comment: I don't understand something: are the variables `names`, `startPos` and `nrNames` already initialized when you call `printNames()`? I mean, your `printNames()` function only needs to print the names which `startPos` points to?

Comment: @LucaPolito According to the question the position and length shall be printed as well. Seems to be some excercise on pointer arithmetics.

Comment: `names[*startPos[i+1]]-names[*startPos[i]]` this subtracts 2 characters, The result is not a length.

Comment: "when I try to print the position in the array and the length they both work incorectly" Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <string.h> // strlen()
#include <stddef.h> // ptrdiff_t, size_t

void printNames(char names[], char *startPos[], int nrNames) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrNames; i += 1) {
        // let's calculate the position of `startPos[i]` inside `names`
        // NOTE: ptrdiff_t is the usual type for the result of pointer subtraction
        ptrdiff_t pos = (ptrdiff_t) (startPos[i] - names);
        // let's calculate the length the usual way
        size_t len = strlen(startPos[i]);

        // NOTE: %td is used to print variables of type `ptrdiff_t`
        printf("startPos[%d]=%td length=%zu string=\"%s\"\n", i, pos, len, startPos[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char names[] = "Ab\0B\0C\0\0";
    char* startPos[3];

    startPos[0] = &names[0];
    startPos[1] = &names[3];
    startPos[2] = &names[5];

    printNames(names, startPos, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
startPos[0]=0 length=2 string="Ab"
startPos[1]=3 length=1 string="B"
startPos[2]=5 length=1 string="C"
```

It should be clear enough, otherwise I may explain more.